# Google Aerial View API, Video not found: No 3d imagery

Tags: google-api, google-aerial-view-api

According to the Google Aerial View API, If the video doesn't yet exist, then the API returns a 404 status code. The instruction is to generate a new video by calling renderVideo.

The video hasn't been previously rendered, and therefore is not yet in Google's database.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Video not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

But what does No 3d imagery mean?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Video not found: No 3d imagery."
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *the other* reason for [Video not found](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/aerial-view/lookup-video.md#video_not_found) in the API. It means: *Google attempted to render the video already, but failed because 3D imagery isn't available for that address.*